# Django test object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm trying to create a test below and I get this message:

**TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable**

on the line: self.stock.expiry_date(yesterday)

**Test**

```
 def test_stock_passed_expiration(self):
        """
        'True' returned when stock is passed it's expiration date.
        """
        yesterday = date.today()-timedelta(days=1)
        self.stock.expiry_date(yesterday)
        self.assertEqual(self.stock.has_expried(), True)
```

**Model:**

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="stocks")
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def has_expried(self):
        if timezone.now > self.expiry_date:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Why is your function named `has_expried` instead of `has_expired`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
self.stock.expiry_date(yesterday)
```

but meant

```
self.stock.expiry_date = yesterday
```

The one you have tries to treat `self.stock.expiry_date` (a datetime object) as if it were a function, leading to that error message.

Comment: I changed it but I get TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to function with your code is this to do with the model method?

Comment: Yes, `timezone.now` is a function, you need to call it like `timezone.now()`. Yay, your test caught a bug :-)

Comment: I'm proud :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your test function you are calling expiry_date as if it were a function.  Instead, set the self.expiry_date attribute as yesterday, save the model and your test should work.

```
def test_stock_passed_expiration(self):
    """
    'True' returned when stock is passed it's expiration date.
    """
    yesterday = date.today()-timedelta(days=1)
    self.stock.expiry_date = yesterday
    self.stock.save()
    self.assertEqual(self.stock.has_expried(), True)
```

Comment: Why save self.stock, doesn't that only make the test slower?

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
self.stock.expiry_date = yesterday
self.stock.save()
```

or

```
self.stock.set(expiry_date=yesterday).save()
```

instead wil help you

Comment: Why save self.stock, doesn't that only make the test slower?

Comment: do I really need to save?

Comment: @Spike only if you're going to enlarge you test